# Xcode5: Cannot preview SpriteKit particle emitter in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, particle-system

When selecting an sks file in xcode, there is no preview of the particle effect. I have tried creating a completely new project.
I can integrate the particle emitter in the app, but can not preview the effect in the editor.

[image: no particle preview available]

Comment: have you tried different particle templates?

Comment: Thank you for comment! Yes, I have tried different templates, the problem persists

Comment: Xcode is v5.0.2? Have you tried rebooting your Mac? Just in case. Also try closing all other apps in case they affect Xcode's rendering of the particle preview.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I am using xcode 5.0.2, I tried closing all the apps and rebooted the mac.

Answer (score 2):

One scenario when this is not working is Mac running on VMware and there is no fix for that. This happened in my case.

The same thing running on my physical MacBook Pro is running just ok and I can see particles everywhere, maybe even outside my screen :)